# Disabling specific image caching in AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm developing an app where people can upload their photos in and edit then (such as giving an effect, cropping, rotating etc). For the up- and downloading, I'm using the AFNetworking framework.

My problem is the following: when I've edited a photo, I upload the new version to the file server. In the app, I'm adjusting the AFImageCache to hold a reference to the new (edited) photo. When I close and open the app again, the old image gets loaded.

So my question is: is there any sort of other cache besides the AFImageCache the iPhone is using? If so, how can I clear the image from that cache so that the new image gets fetched from the server when I restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in cache on the iPhone, so any caching that is happening is either:

1. On the server
2. In code that's within your project

You could try single stepping through in the debugger, seeing where the out of date image data is actually getting loaded from.

Comment: I see that a web request is being made to my photo, but when I go to the url in the browser, I get the new image. Somehow my request doesn't receive the new image. Is this possible?

In the code, the only caching I use, is the caching that comes with AFNetworking, but I've manually cleared the cache before making the request to make sure it's not something in the code.

Comment: How does the server response to the request you see? It is a 304 HTTP code for example? If you single step through the network code, is it actually using data received from the server?

Comment: @JosephH: The iPhone has built-in caching. It's exposed via the `NSURLRequest` class, the base of AFNetworking. Have a look at the documentation of the [initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLRequest/requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:) method.

Comment: @Codo Sorry, should've been clearer. On iOS, there's no built in disk cache / persistent cache that would survive between separate runs of the app.

Comment: @JosephH That's not quite true, either. As of iOS 5, non-SSL responses are cached to disk.

Comment: @matt oh, coo... I stand corrected. Was that a documented change?!

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from same problem the issue was URL of edited image and previous image was same and  url is used as a cache key by AFNetworking uiimage category

in UIImage+afnetworking.m go to

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
```

and then add to it

```
request.cachePolicy=NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;//my change for disabling
```

you can check this [link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-disable-caching-of-particular.html)

Comment: @evya afnetworking makes the emage URL key and uses it to save the image in a object.Though  UIImage+afnetworking.m a category still it uses low level c api to write object in memory and retrive it. you can tweek the code near the same method to disable caching for a flag